# How to map children element of an xml file using RML to create an RDF?

Tags: xml, xpath, rdf, rml-rdf

I'd like to create an RDF using RML mapping. The XML part is shown below. I have made a triple map for "Attribute" and "FB". One of the FB has a child "Attribute", but in the result, each "FB" Triples has "Attribute". Is there any solution for that to make the child "Attribute" unique for just one "FB" element?

```
  <Application ID="A4ABD8400116F035" Name="HotWater">
<SubAppNetwork>
  <FB ID="3D77F5AE3E23F522" Name="HW_setpoint" Type="CAThmiInput" x="360" y="880" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
  <FB ID="38615A5C87F12AA3" Name="HW_pump1" Type="CATmotor" x="2760" y="260" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
  <FB ID="3632883FE07D2F09" Name="HW_pump2" Type="CATmotor" x="2760" y="860" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial">
    <Parameter Name="AutoOn" Value="TRUE" />
  </FB>
  <FB ID="FB64994118EB2489" Name="HW_pidController" Type="CATpidController" x="1000" y="260" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
  <FB ID="1C32C8BEDD84AAA7" Name="HW_sensor" Type="CATsensor" x="360" y="260" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
  <FB ID="97DE5397424C589F" Name="HW_valve" Type="CATvalve" x="1620" y="260" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
  <FB ID="3A265436F99A7B87" Name="HW_compare" Type="COMPARE_1990CFD1468AAE4A6" x="2220" y="260" Namespace="Main">
    <Attribute Name="Configuration.GenericFBType.InterfaceParams" Value="Runtime.Standard#CNT:=2;IN${CNT}:LREAL" />
    <Parameter Name="IN2" Value="0.0" />
  </FB>
  <EventConnections>
    <Connection Source="HW_sensor.CNF" Destination="HW_pidController.REQ" />
    <Connection Source="HW_setpoint.CNF" Destination="HW_pidController.REQ" dx1="110.7709">
      <AvoidsNodes>false</AvoidsNodes>
    </Connection>
    <Connection Source="HW_pidController.CNF" Destination="HW_valve.REQ" />
    <Connection Source="HW_valve.CNF" Destination="HW_compare.REQ" />
    <Connection Source="HW_compare.CNF" Destination="HW_pump1.REQ" />
  </EventConnections>
  <DataConnections>
    <Connection Source="HW_sensor.outValue" Destination="HW_pidController.pv" dx1="41.3125" />
    <Connection Source="HW_setpoint.value" Destination="HW_pidController.sp" dx1="170.7709">
      <AvoidsNodes>false</AvoidsNodes>
    </Connection>
    <Connection Source="HW_pidController.cp" Destination="HW_valve.AutoSP" />
    <Connection Source="HW_compare.GT" Destination="HW_pump1.AutoOn" dx1="70" />
    <Connection Source="HW_valve.cp" Destination="HW_compare.IN1" />
  </DataConnections>
</SubAppNetwork>
```

Mapping:

```
  <#AttributeMapping>
  a rr:TriplesMap;
  rml:logicalSource [
    rml:source "System.xml" ;
    rml:iterator "/System/Application/SubAppNetwork/FB/Attribute";
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:XPath
  ];

rr:subjectMap [
rr:template "http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB/Attribute-{@Name}";
rr:class iec61499:Attribute
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasName;
rr:objectMap [
  rml:reference "@Name"
];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasValue;
rr:objectMap [
  rml:reference "@Value"
];
].


<#FBMapping>
a rr:TriplesMap;
rml:logicalSource [
rml:source "System.xml" ;
rml:iterator "/System/Application/SubAppNetwork/FB";
rml:referenceFormulation ql:XPath
];

rr:subjectMap [
rr:template "http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-{../../../@Name}-{@ID}";
rr:class iec61499:FB
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasID;
rr:objectMap [
  rml:reference "@ID"
];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasName;
rr:objectMap [
  rml:reference "@Name"
];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasType;
rr:objectMap [
  rml:reference "@Type"
];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasX;
rr:objectMap [
  rml:reference "@x"
];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasY;
rr:objectMap [
  rml:reference "@y"
];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasNamespace;
rr:objectMap [
  rml:reference "@Namespace"
];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
rr:predicate iec61499:hasAttribute;
rr:objectMap [
  rr:parentTriplesMap <#AttributeMapping>
];
].
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: HTH: https://rml.io/specs/rml/#logical-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can link a child to its parent in RML with an `rr:joinCondition`:

```
rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate iec61499:hasAttribute;
        rr:objectMap [
            rr:parentTriplesMap <#AttributeMapping>;
            rr:joinCondition [
                rr:child "@Name";
                rr:parent "../@Name"
            ];
        ];
    ].
```

The `rr:joinCondition` will make sure that the join only happens when the values of `rr:child` and `rr:parent` are equal to each other.

I modified your data since the XML was invalid, the `</Application>` end tag was missing, you can find the new data below:

```
<Application ID="A4ABD8400116F035" Name="HotWater">
    <SubAppNetwork>
        <FB ID="3D77F5AE3E23F522" Name="HW_setpoint" Type="CAThmiInput" x="360" y="880" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
        <FB ID="38615A5C87F12AA3" Name="HW_pump1" Type="CATmotor" x="2760" y="260" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
        <FB ID="3632883FE07D2F09" Name="HW_pump2" Type="CATmotor" x="2760" y="860" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial">
            <Parameter Name="AutoOn" Value="TRUE" />
        </FB>
        <FB ID="FB64994118EB2489" Name="HW_pidController" Type="CATpidController" x="1000" y="260" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
        <FB ID="1C32C8BEDD84AAA7" Name="HW_sensor" Type="CATsensor" x="360" y="260" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
        <FB ID="97DE5397424C589F" Name="HW_valve" Type="CATvalve" x="1620" y="260" Namespace="nxtControl.Tutorial" />
        <FB ID="3A265436F99A7B87" Name="HW_compare" Type="COMPARE_1990CFD1468AAE4A6" x="2220" y="260" Namespace="Main">
            <Attribute Name="Configuration.GenericFBType.InterfaceParams" Value="Runtime.Standard#CNT:=2;IN${CNT}:LREAL" />
            <Parameter Name="IN2" Value="0.0" />
        </FB>
        <EventConnections>
            <Connection Source="HW_sensor.CNF" Destination="HW_pidController.REQ" />
            <Connection Source="HW_setpoint.CNF" Destination="HW_pidController.REQ" dx1="110.7709">
                <AvoidsNodes>false</AvoidsNodes>
            </Connection>
            <Connection Source="HW_pidController.CNF" Destination="HW_valve.REQ" />
            <Connection Source="HW_valve.CNF" Destination="HW_compare.REQ" />
            <Connection Source="HW_compare.CNF" Destination="HW_pump1.REQ" />
        </EventConnections>
        <DataConnections>
            <Connection Source="HW_sensor.outValue" Destination="HW_pidController.pv" dx1="41.3125" />
            <Connection Source="HW_setpoint.value" Destination="HW_pidController.sp" dx1="170.7709">
                <AvoidsNodes>false</AvoidsNodes>
            </Connection>
            <Connection Source="HW_pidController.cp" Destination="HW_valve.AutoSP" />
            <Connection Source="HW_compare.GT" Destination="HW_pump1.AutoOn" dx1="70" />
            <Connection Source="HW_valve.cp" Destination="HW_compare.IN1" />
        </DataConnections>
    </SubAppNetwork>
</Application>
```

I reduced your example to the bare minimum and added the `rr:joinCondition` to perform the join only when the `Name` attribute of `FB` matches for the parent and its child:

```
@base <http://example.org/> .
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix iec61499: <http://example.org/iec61499/> . 

<#AttributeMapping>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource [
        rml:source "System.xml";
        rml:referenceFormulation ql:XPath;
        rml:iterator "/Application/SubAppNetwork/FB/Attribute"
    ];

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB/Attribute-{@Name}";
        rr:class iec61499:Attribute
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate iec61499:hasName;
        rr:objectMap [
            rml:reference "@Name"
        ];
    ].

<#FBMapping>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource [
        rml:source "System.xml" ;
        rml:iterator "/Application/SubAppNetwork/FB";
        rml:referenceFormulation ql:XPath
    ];

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-{../../@Name}-{@ID}";
        rr:class iec61499:FB
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate iec61499:hasName;
        rr:objectMap [
            rml:reference "@Name"
        ];
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate iec61499:hasAttribute;
        rr:objectMap [
            rr:parentTriplesMap <#AttributeMapping>;
            rr:joinCondition [
                rr:child "@Name";
                rr:parent "../@Name"
            ];
        ];
    ].
```

If you provide an RML processor these mappings and data, you will get the following output:

```
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB/Attribute-Configuration.GenericFBType.InterfaceParams> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.org/iec61499/Attribute>.
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB/Attribute-Configuration.GenericFBType.InterfaceParams> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasName> "Configuration.GenericFBType.InterfaceParams".
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-3D77F5AE3E23F522> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.org/iec61499/FB>.
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-3D77F5AE3E23F522> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasName> "HW_setpoint".
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-38615A5C87F12AA3> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.org/iec61499/FB>.
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-38615A5C87F12AA3> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasName> "HW_pump1".
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-3632883FE07D2F09> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.org/iec61499/FB>.
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-3632883FE07D2F09> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasName> "HW_pump2".
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-FB64994118EB2489> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.org/iec61499/FB>.
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-FB64994118EB2489> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasName> "HW_pidController".
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-1C32C8BEDD84AAA7> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.org/iec61499/FB>.
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-1C32C8BEDD84AAA7> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasName> "HW_sensor".
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-97DE5397424C589F> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.org/iec61499/FB>.
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-97DE5397424C589F> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasName> "HW_valve".
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-3A265436F99A7B87> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.org/iec61499/FB>.
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-3A265436F99A7B87> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasName> "HW_compare".
<http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB-HotWater-3A265436F99A7B87> <http://example.org/iec61499/hasAttribute> <http://sth/example#/SubAppNetwork/FB/Attribute-Configuration.GenericFBType.InterfaceParams>.
```

**Note**: I contribute to RML and its technologies.